# Databinding vs Control Setting of values

Tags: .net, design-patterns, data-binding

My question today is more theoretical than technical, but here goes. Can anyone tell me the real difference /and/or issues between the following two Paradigms :

```xml
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Name="myTextbox" Text="{Binding ....}" />
```

versus Code-behind setting of the control properties:

```cs
myTextbox.text = myEntity.mypropertyvalue
```

In other words, what are the benefits of building a ObservableCollection for the entity  and then databinding ? It seems mostly overkill doesnt it? Especially in my case where it's a one way binding and the entity contains 2 properties at most.

Any comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Databinding features:

- Most important: Keep UI and business logic decoupled, so UI and business logic tied only via well-known protocol which consist of binding names (bound properties and commands)
- Notifications when binding source/target changes
- Automatically update bound source whilst updating data in UI, for example when user editing TextBox udnerlying data would be affected as well